# XCode EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on device but not simulator - debugging with breakpoints

Tags: xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access, breakpoints

I'm not sure what happened, I think I did not make any significant changes to the code, but now I cannot run or debug the app.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x2fd77d4c)
```

I cannot even insert breakpoint before the error, it is while splashscreen is shown (so AppDelegate didFinishLoadingWithOptions is not called).

Where should I try to put breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Changing deployment target to 6.1, running the app and then changing back to 5.0... Puzzled thought....